# woocommerce multiple products recipe page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am currently looking for a solution for recipe pages.

Basically, I will have a blog post recipes where we will use our products to make something and users can read. I would like to add a button below the recipe page for example "Make this recipe" and when the button is clicked, all the ingredients that are used to make this recipe are added to the cart.

Is there a plugin that I can use so when I write the blog post, I can select the products that is added to the cart for different recipes?

Or do I need to get a developer to do this?

Comment: You can use https://codecanyon.net/item/visual-composer-page-builder-for-wordpress/242431 it's a drag and drop plugin and you'll be able to build any type of layout with it.

Comment: I think this would need a dev, hope this will be some plugin to do that, but i doubt that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [WooCommerce Product Bundles](https://woocommerce.com/products/product-bundles/), this will allow you to bundle all the ingredients into one product which you can add via a [shortcode](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/) ie `[add_to_cart id="99"]` on the post.

Comment: Thank you fro the solution. I have checked the plugin and raised my needs to them. I will see if this fits. Thanks again.

Comment: That plugin will work I've done something similar before.

Answer (score -1):

This plugin will take care of allowing your customers to build their order exactly the way you want: https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-order-builder-combo-products-extra-options/20839198

Then you can change add to cart to what ever you want by adding this to your theme functions.php file

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_cart_button_text' ); 
function woo_custom_cart_button_text() {
        return __( 'Make this recipe', 'woocommerce' );
}
```